# Receiving and Saving a Json File on Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Environment:

- ASP.NET Core Web Application
- Target Framework: NET Core 3.1
- Visual Studio: 2019 Community, 16.6.5

Issue:
I am trying to receive Json from a client and then store that information (per request) as a file locally on the server, preferably not in webroot.

So far... I have read a number of articles and tried a number of things, so many things that I'm lost on the file size/POST size restraints part but more importantly on the actual file saving to disk part.

What I have tried so far beyond reading...
I created a new Empty API Controller called SendResults1 and with the method below I am able to get the Json POST going.

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index([FromBody] JsonElement body)
        {
            string json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(body);
            var size = json.Length * sizeof(Char);

            if (size < 20000)
                return Ok();
            else
                return BadRequest("File size too large.");
        }
```

Any help on how to store the file on the server locally (preferably not under webroot, or accessible by the client once posted.)

Comment: _Assuming_ that error code from Postman is your API response, exactly what/how are you sending your payload via Postman?

Comment: Yes, it is the response. Just strings.

{
  "stringA": "asd87sdada87",
  "stringB": "2020-09-11-15-24-17",
  "stringC": "asdadasdadadadasdad"
}

Comment: Check: Your API endpoint is expecting a `string` not `json` - so check your Postman request (it should be sending a `string` in the `POST` payload`). Here's a [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) that should help (model binding instead of strings, if that's what you're after). Hth

Comment: I just tried a function that was expecting a Json instead and that worked. I might stick with that. I'll update the thread above to reflect my next problem of saving the file and or putting constraints around size.

Comment: @EdSF Thank you for that by the way and thank you for your responses in general.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to those that assisted: mods and users alike.

Here is where I ended up, fits all the criteria I was looking for.

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class SendResults1 : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index([FromBody] JsonElement body)
        {
            string json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(body);
            var size = json.Length * sizeof(Char);

            if (size < 20000)
            {
                string filePath = @"C:\Temp";
                string fileName = Path.GetRandomFileName();
                try
                {
                    using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(filePath, fileName)))
                        await outputFile.WriteAsync(json);
                   return Ok();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //INSERT LOGGING CODE HERE - TO CAPTURE THE EXCEPTION
                    return BadRequest("Unspecified create error"); //Purposely being ambiguous or obfuscating the actual error and file path.
                }
            }    
            else
                return BadRequest("Error: Malformed data sent.");
        }
    }
```

The reason for the ambiguity above for the exception is that if there is a file write exception the client/caller will see the exception and file path on the local server. To capture this exception I'll use a web logger.

Comment: @mason The TL;DR: After writing the above I put a try/catch around it. The if exist error was a stop-gap until I could fully test the code and try to make it fail. Will update the answer. Thank you for the comment.